# How to autostart android app automatically without user permission?

Tags: android, service, background, location, autostart

I want to use background service in android . For that i have used background service, foreground service and job scheduler as well. But my app doesn't work in background without auto start option enabled.

I have added background , foreground services and job scheduler also.
I have added code to redirect the user to autostart setting enable.
As i have seen in many apps they won't ask user for the permission to enable autostart (ex. whatsapp, flipkart).

```
    private void scheduleJob() {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MyJobService.class);
 JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE)
    //                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                    .setPersisted(true) // job alive even if we reboot
    //                .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000) // 15 mins
                    .setPeriodic(5 * 1000) // 5 secs
                    .build();
            JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
            int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);

            if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Job Scheduled");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Job Scheduling failed");
            }
```

My app doesn't work in background without auto start option enabled.
        I want it enabled automatically.
[Autostart enables automatically when you install app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXkPq.jpg)

Comment: what you're talking about is making a service whatsapp and other apps which do this usually have a service attached in background and they also have a broadcast receiver to listen for boot completion hence what they basically do is run that service and create a push notification hence when that notification is clicked app is launched!

Comment: I have broadcast receiver which listens for boot completion. I want the app to be enabled autostart automatically.

Comment: you can't autostart app directly but you can easily implement that with service and additional permissions

Comment: Can you help me with that please ?

Comment: get the any solution?

Comment: Not yet, using with user permissions

Answer (score 0):

Okay to implement that create a sticky service and register that in your main activity and on boot completed you should refresh your service whenever you need to restart the application just refresh your service and either create a notification or just refresh your service which this code:

```
public static Boolean RestartApp1(Activity activity) {
    if (!GlobalData.checkAndRequestPermissions(activity)) {
        Intent i = activity.getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(activity.getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(i);

        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


if (GlobalData.RestartApp1(activity)) {
        getSharedData();
        findViews();
        initViews();
        setActionBarSDK();
}
```